# google-authenticator for two-factor-authentication support with openvpn client on linux

Tags: openvpn, google-authenticator, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to get openvpn *client* to work with google-authenticator and two-factor-authentication. I cannot alter the server in any way (i.e. I cannot do password/token concactenation via pam mods, etc).

I assume this would require recompiling the source code to include two-factor-authentication functionality from [google code](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/), so as to get prompted for two-factor-authentication code, after entering password.

Has anyone done this, or have any tips on doing this?

This is similar to the Viscosity software for osx/windoze, which uses the [openvpn source code](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn)  and adds the google-authenticator two-factor-authentication functionality.   Unfortunately Viscosity, although based on openvpn, is closed source.

Comment: I am really confused how you expect to do anything if you can't change the server?  What exactly do you mean by "can't change the server".

Comment: What does tag [2fa] and [mfa] stand for? Two/Multi factor authentication or other meaning like company 2fa . com/?

Comment: @masegaloeh 2-factor authentication (multi-factor authentication)..... feel free to read up on google authenticator

Comment: @zoredache the server configuration is not able to be seen/changed,..... the openvpn *client* needs to support 2fa in order to connect to blackboxed openvpn server... the functionality i am looking for is the same as the closed source Viscosity openvpn-based client software... you dont need to touch the server to use Viscosity with 2fa/mfa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured this out. openvpn 2.3.6 supports this by default (no need to recompile, plugins, etc).

So I need to add to ovpn conf file:

```
static-challenge "Enter Google Authenticator Code" 1
```